# how to deserialize string value to List using jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson

there is a json text like this

```json
{"name":"g1","users":"[{\"name\":\"u1\",\"id\":1},{\"name\":\"u2\",\"id\":2}]"}
```

how to deserialize this text to object?
my struct class is like this

```java
static class User {
    private String name;
    private Long id;
}
static class Group {
    private String name;
    private List<User> users;
}
```

but how to deserialize the text to object

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Group group = objectMapper.readValue(s, Group.class);
```

Comment: on first glance it should work, what error You have when running this code ?

Comment: It seems that your JSON is not good, it should look like `{"name":"g1","users":[{"name":"u1","id":1},{"name":"u2","id":2}]}`

Comment: yes the json is not good. the json of the users property is a string .my problem is how to auto deserialize the string to list。

Answer (score 0):

I'm try imp a JsonDeserializer like this.

```java
public class RawJsonDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> implements ContextualDeserializer {
    private final JavaType type;

    public RawJsonDeserializer() {
        this.type = SimpleType.constructUnsafe(Object.class);
    }

    public RawJsonDeserializer(JavaType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        System.out.println(property.getType());
        return new RawJsonDeserializer<>(property.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return ((ObjectMapper) p.getCodec()).readValue(p.getText(), type);
    }
}
```

and i apply it on my proterty

```
 @JsonDeserialize(using = RawJsonDeserializer.class, contentAs = WaybillItem.class) @JsonProperty("responseItems")
```